# Prevent corrupted executable from launching on OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, security, launchd

I have a process(Launch Daemon) that gets launched by launchd in root context in OS X. The process is code signed. Still if I corrupt the binary, it loads again. To corrupt the binary, I open the executable in hex editor, and do a find and replace for any string. Is there a way to prevent this process from launching in case it is corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides a [code signing framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/) that allows an executable to check its own signature and test if the application has been tampered with.

Start by obtaining a code object with the call to [SecCodeCopySelf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCodeCopySelf), then use the retrieved `SecCodeRef` to call [SecCodeCheckValidity](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCodeCheckValidity) or [SecCodeCheckValidityWithErrors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCodeCheckValidityWithErrors).

It's up to your application to quit if it encounters a problem with the validity. As it's running in the root context, it could also unload itself from launchd.

Note that the time take to verify the application is dependent upon its size and number of files. A very large app bundle, such as XCode, can take about 3 minutes, though a small application will barely be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Generally OS X's Gatekeeper will not prevent you from executing a binary that is not code signed or mis-signed, so long as you have already removed the quarantine attribute after downloading to approve it ("xxx is an applications downloaded from the Intenet..."). Also it it will stand down if it seems like you are executing it on purpose (right click, Open, or execute in a Terminal). After something has been approved to run, GateKeeper is done.

So this is a nice safeguard but very weak stuff, frankly. Nothing like iOS.

For your purposes, you may want to check out [Ostiarius](https://objective-see.com/products/ostiarius.html). This is recently-released tool that will cause the OS X kernel to refuse to execute any binary that is unsigned (or modified) and also from the Internet from running, period. You could use `xattr` to add the quarantine attribute to your binary so it will be affected.

And/or, in a launchd script that calls it, use `codesign -dv` to check the signature yourself before you are willing to launch it. You could also sandbox the app to make sure that if it were hijacked it would not be entitled to do absolutely everything.

Because this is a launchd process, the same security researcher has another free tool called [BlockBlock](https://objective-see.com/products/blockblock.html) that might interest you. I believe that it would prevent the binary from getting replaced in the first place until you approve it.

Frankly everything this guy has made is pretty cool. May want to check out the rest.

Comment: Whilst I agree that Patrick's tool, Ostiarius is great, it's not going to solve the problem. Even though the binary may be corrupt, it's still signed and Ostiarius doesn't verify the integrity of the application. In addition, if the user has previously accepted the application to execute, its quarantine flag is removed and Ostiarius will still allow the application to run.

Comment: Not sure about that.

Comment: `sudo xattr -w com.apple.quarantine "0002;56dffb86;Safari;0EC7F021-2F3C-43CC-BC47-7981517CD429" /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`, then run `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`, it won't get removed if it's just ran at the console.

Comment: Consider - if someone can modify your binary, any solution that involves that program checking itself and self-aborting will not really work. It could be neutered just like cracked Mac App Store apps.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain properly. Whilst the attribute is there, there's another flag, that is marked when the user has approved the app to open, regardless of gatekeeper. The kext for Ostiarius checks for this and allows it if that flag is set. It's documented in Patrick's slides for his talk [Gatekeeper Exposed](https://www.synack.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/GatekeeperExposed.pdf). Note step 2 on slide 58 - *ignore 'user-approved' binaries*

Comment: *any solution that involves that program checking itself and self-aborting will not really work* - I agree. Perhaps that's why Apple don't shout too loudly about that API!

Comment: Huh - that part would not just be checking to see if in the first 4 bytes of the xattr it it's been bitwise OR'd with 0x0040? `0002;` to `0042;` in the example quarantine attribute I posted above? I can't see where (from the disassembly, or the visual aids) it's indicating there is an outside store.

Comment: (Before and after running the flags will remain wherever I put them when I try it.)